# PHP MYSQL Table Row Click to Display Details of the Data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to display more details of the data when the table row `<tr>` is clicked. But I have no idea how to implement it. Here's my code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "hotel_dir";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT hotel_img, hotel_name, hotel_address, hotel_phone FROM hotel";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td><img src=".$row["hotel_img"].
        "></td><td>".$row["hotel_name"].
        "<br />".$row["hotel_address"].
        "</td><td>".$row["hotel_phone"].
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Here's the image.
[hotel list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJe6k.jpg)

The problem is, I'm trying to pass it to hotel.php showing more details of the hotel when the table row is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have an Id field in your `hotel` table you can include it and have an anchor tag to link to other page with this id,
actually some thing like this:

For SQL statement:

for SQL statement you select id and the previous fields that you had selected already, as usually id is a unique column in tables you can get detail of one row and show all detail of specied id.

Here in this page your sql statement should change to :

`$sql = "SELECT id,hotel_img, hotel_name, hotel_address, hotel_phone FROM hotel";`

and in the `detail.php` page your SQL statement must be something like this(of course I didn't consider security stuff):

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM hotel where id=".$_GET['id'];`

for your table : 
Here I just added `a` tag call detail.php file with parameter `id` that you can get it in `details.php` for show details

```
echo "<tr>
   <td><a href="http://yoursite.dev/detail.php?id=".$row["id"]>See Details</a></td>
   <td><img src=".$row["hotel_img"]."></td>
   <td>".$row["hotel_name"].
      "<br />".$row["hotel_address"].
      "
   </td>
   <td>".$row["hotel_phone"].
      "
   </td>
</tr>";
```

And in your `detail.php` file you get parameter `id` with `$_GET['id']` and show more detail for specified `id`

Comment: Can you explain further? Like put comments on the code so that It's understandable. Sorry I'm new to Php and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: I added some details.I hope it be helpfull

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the further explanation, but how exactly do I do it on the detail.php side?

Comment: Actually nevermind! I got it worked! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Can I actually implement, instead of having another tab to "See More Details", I just click on the TR instead? So, whenever the table row is clicked, it shows the detail of the hotel?

Comment: Yes,you can load all data and just hide them and on click on show detail show them. you can see jQuery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` function