# Display details when user click table row

Tags: mysql, node.js, html, security, web

I have following tables in my Database:

> - Student (student_id, email, name, ...)
> - Course (course_id, course_name, ...)
> - Enrollment (student_id, course_id, marks,...)

I Want to implement this functionality:

> 1. When admin want to search list of all students in particular city,
>      the list is displayed as HTML table.

This can be implemented by just querying student table.

> 2. When admin click on any row (from the table we have displayed in 1.)
>      then admin should see list of all courses the student has enrolled
>      in.

My question is how should I implement this? 
I can think of following ways:
**Way 1:** 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45135144/3494107
I need to have some way to identify which row admin has clicked, for this I can pass the student_id also in the table in result for 1 (display list of all student) but as student_id does not convey any information to admin about student I can just hide it in `data-*` attribute of `<tr>` or in `<a href=/enrollment/${student_id}>` so that I can use this to identify which row admin has clicked. Some of my friend told me that I should not expose surrogate key, this is bad for security. So is there any way I can associate this student_id to table row but hide from the user or it is OK to expose surrogate key content to user? 
**Way 2:** 
 I can create a temporary table containing all student from particular city in DB and assign the row ID to it. Now in result I can add this row ID for each row into data-* attribute. This row ID does not convey any information about what is actual student_id and I can use this row ID to query temporary table to get actual student_id which I can use to search in enrollment table. Now I need to delete this temporary table when user navigate away from current page (go to other functionality), now how should I detect when user have moved away from this page?


**I want to understand what security issue I can have if I expose surrogate key to user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No security issues as such if you expose the `student_id` but at business point of view it's not much acceptable.

If these tables are only viewed by admins then it is not a problem in either way.

If these are viewable by even by a guest then better not expose the `student_id`. Not for the security of your database but for the security of your business. It might expose your strength and weakness.

You can use `student_registration_no` instead. It might be slow, considering a `VARCHAR` entry, but not humanly detectable.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you meant when you said it might expose your business strength and weakness? The scenario I have given is hypothetical. In reality I wanted to implement subscription based service to customer something like asana.com or jira.com where the admin role of customer should be able to see list of projects or list of employee they have and after clicking a particular employee they should be able to see list of all task under project or employee. I can see asana put the ID into link `https://app.asana.com/0/63...18/board` but I am not sure that is surrogate key or not

Comment: @LovelyGuyAnSh By business strength and weakness, I meant suppose you have 100 students registered in your site but you are advertising as more than 500 students are there so easily one can find that you are showing some false data, just an example. The security part is not that vital here as a hacker will not depend on the values those you are showing. They will directly go for SQL Injection or other attacks to extract their required values from your database. Not only the sites those you have mentioned display the ID but this site itself is doing so. Even forum softwares, like vB does it.